# Using Bootstrap Datetimepicker DOM object on multiple ng-views in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am trying to implement two ng-views on an angular app, each of them using a Bootstrap Datetimepicker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) to select a date. For each view, I have a javascript $(document).ready function (outside of the angular controller, naturally) which configures the Datetimepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
          format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          inline: true,
          sideBySide: false,
          minDate: moment()
      });

      var today = $('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").getMoment();

      $('#datetimepicker12').on('dp.change', function(e) {
          angular.element(document.getElementById('reservations')).scope().setDate(e.date);
      });


    });
```

This code configures the DOM div with id #datetimepicker12

When I load the initial view, everything works as expected and the datetimepicker is properly configured and shown. But when I change the ng-view, naturally the $(document).ready is not called again, as it was already called before when first loading the app, and the datetimepicker object that should appear on the new ng-view is not configured once again. As a result, it is not shown any longer. Neither on the second nor first partial. It only appears again if I refresh the page. But then disappears if I change the partial inside the app.

Is there a way around this? I thought a possibility would be to try to call a function outside the angular controller in order for it to be able to configure the object with the .datetimepicker() function. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What actually solved my issue was creating an angular directive for the datetimepicker. With it, I was able to access the JQuery object I wanted and use the datetimepicker formatting functions. I applied the following directive:

```
module.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
  return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.datetimepicker({
             format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                inline: true,
                sideBySide: false,
                minDate: moment()
       });

       var today = $('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").getMoment();

       element.on('dp.change', function(e) {
             angular.element(document.getElementById('reservations')).scope().setDate(e.date);
         });
     }
});
```

Then on the DOM element, I just added the 'datetimepicker' attribute to the div which held the datetimepicker.

Answer (score 0):

you can use viewContentLoaded event for this. You need to inject $rootScope

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  $('#datetimepicker12').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      inline: true,
      sideBySide: false,
      minDate: moment()
  });

  var today = $('#datetimepicker12').data("DateTimePicker").getMoment();

  $('#datetimepicker12').on('dp.change', function(e) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
         //need to assign ng-model='modelToPopulate' to the DOM element
         $scope.modelToPopulate = e.date;
      });
  });

});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. But my problem is with the code that goes inside the function. I would not know how to reference DOM elements and functions from inside an angular controller.